# Powershell: How to select a specific value from an output?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to only pullout the specific vualue from an output of a command below?

```
applicationName applicationId attributes
--------------- ------------- ----------
Keno_Test_App          115345 {@{name=Regions; id=2722; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Project type; id=5162; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Interface type; id=5163; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Data classification; id=5164; value=(Not Set)}...}
Keno_Test_App2         118991 {@{name=Regions; id=2722; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Project type; id=5162; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Interface type; id=5163; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Data classification; id=5164; value=(Not Set)}...}
```

I try doing something like this but its still captures both output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $getapp.applicationName
Keno_Test_App
Keno_Test_App2
```

Is there away to get an output like this:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $getapp.applicationName
Keno_Test_App
```

or:

```
applicationName applicationId attributes
--------------- ------------- ----------
Keno_Test_App          115345 {@{name=Regions; id=2722; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Project type; id=5162; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Interface type; id=5163; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Data classification; id=5164; value=(Not Set)}...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$getapp.applicationName` outputs this:

```
Keno_Test_App
Keno_Test_App2
```

then `($getapp.applicationName)[0]` will output:

```
Keno_Test_App
```

If `$getapp` outputs this:

```
applicationName applicationId attributes
--------------- ------------- ----------
Keno_Test_App          115345 {@{name=Regions; id=2722; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Project type; id=5162; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Interface type; id=5163; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Data classification; id=5164; value=(Not Set)}...}
Keno_Test_App2         118991 {@{name=Regions; id=2722; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Project type; id=5162; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Interface type; id=5163; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Data classification; id=5164; value=(Not Set)}...}
```

then `$getapp[0]` will output:

```
applicationName applicationId attributes
--------------- ------------- ----------
Keno_Test_App          115345 {@{name=Regions; id=2722; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Project type; id=5162; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Interface type; id=5163; value=(Not Set)}, @{name=Data classification; id=5164; value=(Not Set)}...}
```

Comment: Hi Thomas,

Thank you for the quick answer. Can this work with Select-Object -ExpandProperty

to remove the tornicate on the end?

Comment: `$getapp[0] | Select-Object -Property applicationName, applicationId`

Comment: Just a question @Thomas, is there a way to use the value name for the filter or is it only by its logal numeraical position [0],[1],[2]..etc..

Comment: @kenomote It is an array. In this case, you have to reference the elements by numbers.